# If statement error in Python

Tags: python

There seems to be a recurring error in my Python Code... The problem I presume is within the `if` statement, is there a possibility you could help me? I am doing an assignment at school and it appears that if the user guesses the word, they get congratulated and if they don't get it, they have to try again.

My code:

```
import time
import random
import os

words = open("Words.txt","r")
WordList = []

for lines in words:

 WordList.append(lines)
 WordList=[line.rstrip('\n')for line in WordList]


print(WordList[0:3])
print(WordList[3:6])
print(WordList[6:9])
time.sleep(2)
os.system(['clear','cls'][os.name == 'nt'])

random.shuffle(WordList)

print(WordList[0:3])
print(WordList[3:6])
print(WordList[6:9])

removedword = (WordList[9])

print("---------------------------")

guesses = 0

while guesses <3:
guess = input("What is the removed word?")
guesses = guesses + 1

  if guess == removedword:
      print("You have guessed correctly!")

  else:
      print("Fail")
```

Inside the shell:

```
['NIGHT', 'SMOKE', 'GHOST']
['TOOTH', 'ABOUT', 'CAMEL']
['BROWN', 'FUNNY', 'CHAIR']
['TOOTH', 'BROWN', 'CHAIR']
['PRICE', 'SMOKE', 'FUNNY']
['ABOUT', 'NIGHT', 'CAMEL']
---------------------------
What is the removed word?GHOST
You have guessed correctly!
What is the removed word?GHOST
You have guessed correctly!
What is the removed word?GHOST
You have guessed correctly!
```

Comment: what error are you getting? can you provide a traceback ?

Comment: Can you please arrange your code properly and ask question with error detials.

Comment: The code does exactly what you just described. - by design, what was it you wanted it to, since you say its an error?

Comment: The error is that when I type in the correct answer, it will ask me for the answer again. I have currently set it so that if they get the answer correct, it will automatically set the 'guesses' variable to 3

Comment: where do you set `guesses` to 3? that's not in the code in your question

Comment: I did it after asking the question, and I placed it under the 'if' section

Comment: You just need to put a `break` when the user guess correctly. It will exit the `while` loop.

Comment: Okay, thank you. However, what if I wanted to make it so that if they guess it incorrectly, it will print "Try again" but if they reach 3 attempts and fail the 3rd, how can I make it say "Game Over" without saying "try again"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your while-loop counts to 3 and doesn't stop even though your answer is correct. To avoid this you need to check if answer is correct and break the loop.

Here's the altered code:

```
import time
import random
import os

words = open("Words.txt","r")
WordList = []

for lines in words:
    WordList.append(lines)
    WordList=[line.rstrip('\n')for line in WordList]


print(WordList[0:3])
print(WordList[3:6])
print(WordList[6:9])
time.sleep(2)
os.system(['clear','cls'][os.name == 'nt'])

random.shuffle(WordList)

print(WordList[0:3])
print(WordList[3:6])
print(WordList[6:9])

removedword = (WordList[9])
#printed this so I could win every time
#print(removedword)

print("---------------------------")

guesses = 0
#Added flag 
unanswered = True

#while guesses less than 3 and question is unanswered 
while guesses <3 and unanswered:
    guess = input("What is the removed word?")
    guesses = guesses + 1
    if guess == removedword:
        print("You have guessed correctly!")
        #correct answer, changes flag
        unanswered = False
    else:
        print("Fail")

if unanswered:
    print("Game over!")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
guesses = 0
flag = 0
while guesses <3:
 guess = input("What is the removed word?")
 guesses = guesses + 1

 if guess == removedword:
     print("You have guessed correctly!")
     flag = 1
     break
  else:
     print("Fail")

if flag == 0:
  print("Game over")
```

Comment: It will print Fail 3 times rather then load third time Game Over!!!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
guesses = 0

while guesses <3:
    guess = input("What is the removed word?")
    guesses = guesses + 1

    if guess == removedword:
      print("You have guessed correctly!")
      break
    else:
      if guesses == 3:
        print("Game over")
      else:
        print("Try again")
```